# Best way to implement real-time features in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Recently I've been looking for a solution to implement real-time updating web pages, for example, Twitter-like news feed or real-time chat. I've discovered some ways, as Pusher service, faye, and quite a lot of ruby gems, like private_pub or sync.

The problem is that this solutions don't seem to be a completely right way to follow. Pusher is rather expensive, and in fact I would not prefer to use other servie in my project. Faye seems insecure, and it is quite hard to implement security for it. Private_pub does the right thing, but last commit on github was in 2013 and in fact it is quite outdated.

All in all, ways that I have discovered do not seem to be professional-grade solutions for Rails startups. I have come up to the question whether I should completely switch to NodeJS or other technologies, or I can integrate NodeJS app inside a Rails one?

To sum up, is there such solution for Rails framework, or switch to another technologies is inevitable?

Comment: Did you look at [the Plezi framework](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi)? It's a web-app server+framework with native Websockets and RESTful routing support. I'm not sure it's production-ready, but it could probably provide an alternative to socket.io allowing you to share code with your Rails app. With some work, it might be able to replace Rails for some applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not help you right now, but at RailsConf last month DHH announced that Rails 5 will add support for websockets via a new library called ActionCable.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMlX9i9Icno

Answer (score 0):

[MessageBus](https://github.com/SamSaffron/message_bus) might be a good fit. It's currently used in [Discourse](http://discourse.org) to implement live updates.

I'm also not sure what your security concerns about Faye are exactly. You should have no issues if everything is operating over HTTPS with proper CORS settings.

As for a mixed Node/Rails solution, you could push some list (e.g. post and list of those to be notified) on an update in the Rails app to a Redis instance. A Node app subscribed to Redis could then notify clients to make a request back to the Rails server for the latest updates.

Comment: [I have a small gem with Node.js and Rails app integration with Redis as relay.](https://github.com/fishbullet/socket_pocket) it is just overview of the  [realtime-rails](https://github.com/mikeatlas/realtime-rails)